# How to trim all spaces except those within quotes for large JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, linux, space

I am currently working on a large JSON file, and wish to shorten it by deleting all extra spaces, tabs, returns, etc. that are not within quotes. The file is some 100,000 lines of code and hard for my other scripts to use it quickly. The file originally looks like:

```
{
  "path": "/math/", 
  "id": "math", 
  "title": "Math Title",       
  "icon_url": "/images/power-mode/badges/circles-40x40.png",   
  "contains": [
    "Topic", 
    "Video", 
   "Exercise"
  ], 
  "children": [], 
  "parent_id": "root",
  "ancestor_ids": [
    "root"
  ], 
  "description": "null", 
  "kind": "Topic", 
  "h_position": -10,
  "v_position": 6, 
  "slug": "math"
}
```

and I wish for it to look like this after deleting unnecessary spaces, tabs,returns, etc:

```
{"path":"/math/","id":"math","title":"Math Title","icon_url":"/images/power-mode/badges/circles-40x40.png",     
"contains":["Topic","Video","Exercise"],"children":[],"parent_id":"root","ancestor_ids":["root"],   
"description": "null","kind":"Topic","h_position":-10,"v_position":6,"slug":"math"}
```

Basically every space should be deleted except for those within quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the json into code and then output it to file specifying a compact format, your spaces within quotes will be preserved in the strings.

In python you could use the native json libraries

```
import json
json.loads(your filestream)
json.dumps(your output stream) // the native output of json.dumps is compact
```

Details in the python docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

But you should be able to do the same technique in any language that handles json.

Comment: The output default of is not compact, since it adds spaces after  commas and colons. You need to pass the `separators=(',', ':')` argument to `json.dumps` to archieve a truly compact output.

Comment: Also, `json.dumps` escapes Unicode chars as `\uXXXX`, even when it's not required by the JSON specification. So your file might end up actually being larger, not smaller.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)'s `-c` or `--compact-output` option:

```
jq -c '' < your-file.json
```

Demo:

```
$ echo '
> {
>   "a": "b"
> }' | jq -c ''
{"a":"b"}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, although you might want also use `-M` too to switch of colors.

Answer (score 1):

**Why not just pipe it through perl???**

```
perl -0pe 's#((^[^"]+")|("[^"]+$)|("[^"]+")|(^[^"]+$))#($x=$1)=~s/\s+/ /g;$x#ge'
```

- -0 will set the field-separator to null so the while(<>) will see one big line and you can handle multiple lines with only whitespace without generating extra spaces.
- -p does the *while(<>) print* bit for you.
- -e says this is our perl code to run.

The code basically matches:

- Between the start-of-line and first quote.
- Between last quote and end of line.
- Between two quotes, which thanks to the last two matches will only be text that is outside quotes.
- Or lines with no quotes at all.

And then it replaces all sets of one or more whitespace characters with a single space.

Basically [replace spaces only in between quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499798/replace-spaces-only-in-between-quotation-marks)  with slight modifications....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [JSON minifier online](http://www.httputility.net/json-minifier.aspx). 
Make a Google search for a JSON minifier. [Google](https://www.google.ht/search?q=json%20minifier&oq=json%20minifier&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6227j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Here is what the JSON minifier returned to me:

```
{"path":"/math/","id":"math","title":"Math Title","icon_url":"/images/power-mode/badges/circles-40x40.png","contains":["Topic","Video","Exercise"],"children":[],"parent_id":"root","ancestor_ids":["root"],"description":"null","kind":"Topic","h_position":-10,"v_position":6,"slug":"math"}
```

You can see that it doesn't remove the spaces between the quotes. e.g "Math Title"

Comment: No that won't work because then it will delete the spaces within quotes

Comment: @ibanez221 No, it doesn't.

Comment: My file may be too large, because the minifier you provided (And a few others I tried) don't return code